# cannot configure react-router to run on plunkr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, plunker

i'm starting to teach myself react now and i currently starting to play with react-router.
For some reason ,my project cannot run with Router tag on this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SksvxfGgnNndJYekeLtK?p=preview)

```
    <Router history={browserHistory}> 
     <Route path="/" component={SearchPage}></Route>
   </Router>
```

The error is "Router not defined"

I know - very basic question, but may be thats reason it will be very easy to answer

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can use it something like that (es6):

   ```
   const {Router, Link, hashHistory, Route, withRouter} = ReactRouter;
   ```

   http://plnkr.co/edit/SzowouqjShMZiiXtlD5b?p=preview
2. or if you prefer es5

   ```
   var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
   var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
   var hashHistory = ReactRouter.hashHistory;
   ```

   http://plnkr.co/edit/UznT9V3aMnvzVfsI5ua7?p=preview
3. also you can use es6 modules with webpackbin

   ```
   import {Router, Route, hashHistory} from 'react-router';
   ```

   http://www.webpackbin.com/Ny87fO0Kb